# Unable to Step in to .net framework source code

Tags: .net

I am able to load the symbols but not able to step-in. How to achieve this?

This is for .Net 3.5 SP1

Comment: Try turning off the "Enable Just My Code" setting at the general debugging options.
Anyway, the answer for your question seems to be right there: [http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug through .NET Framework source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373796/how-to-debug-through-net-framework-source-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you enable "Enable .NET Framework source stepping"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139269/how-do-you-enable-enable-net-framework-source-stepping)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clear out your local symbol cache as well. If you've ever downloaded symbols from the regular symbol server those will be used first.